# Port For Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, port, windows-task-scheduler

Does anyone know what the port used to run the task scheduler is in Windows?

Does the task scheduler have a port? May I know what the port is, or how to look for the port that the server using to run the task scheduler is?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an older question, but maybe this will help.  If I correctly understand what you're asking, you can use Task Scheduler itself or use [schtasks.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks) from the command prompt to manage tasks on a remote computer.  I can't find a source, but can tell you that you will need port 135 open in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't expose task scheduler APIs over the network, so there's no port. If you wanted to control the task scheduler remotely, you would need to expose it to the network yourself, by writing a small server process to expose the scheduler API (inasmuch as it's available from the userspace - most of it is available only from the kernel space, i.e. from drivers).

Your idea isn't as outlandish as it may seem, though. There are operating systems where even the most basic subsystems communicate using messages sent over abstract communication ports. Minix 3, for example, by default runs the scheduler embedded in the kernel process. But the scheduler certainly *can be run as a separate, communicating process in the user space*. [This user-mode implementation of process scheduling in Minix 3](http://www.minix3.org/docs/scheduling/report.pdf) does what you think of (almost): it is a process scheduler that runs as a separate process ("server"), and the rest of the system only communicates with it via messages. This message interface to the scheduler process (or any process, in fact), can be easily exposed over a network interface - this was done for Minix by [adding a NET server to implement remote process communication](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/322609.323152).

Answer (score 0):

It uses port 445 for Windows Server 2012 and later;
135/139 for the older ones.

See https://cyberark-customers.force.com/s/article/Required-Ports-for-Windows-Scheduled-Tasks-Windows-Server-2012

> For Windows Server 2012 / 2012 R2 or any modern system, only port 445 is needed as it should support SMB over TCP. Port 139 is needed for older systems as it uses NETBIOS over TCP instead to transmit SMB communication from one system to another.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32673531)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There is no port, nor a server. Task scheduler is just a way of scheduling things to run.
Its ran entirely on the local machine, with no net communication.